# Property 'move' not found on object of type 'theMove *'

Tags: swift, objective-c, iso

i have 2 classes the first One in objective-c  & second in swift

in in objective-c Class i want to call some Code from swift but i get this Error

```
Property 'move' not found on object of type 'theMove *'
```

in the swift i have this code

```
@objc enum Move : NSInteger
{
   case one, two 
}
 
@objc public class theMove :NSObject
{    
    var move : Move
    @objc init(move : Move)
    {
        self.move = move
    }
}
```

in the objective -c

the error appear when i call fristTurn.move

```
@property (nonatomic) theMove * fristTurn;

fristTurn.move
```

could you help me to solve this Error

Answer (score 1):

Either

`@objc var move : Move`

or

`@objcMembers public class TheMove :NSObject`

Allowing

```
@property (nonatomic) TheMove *firstTurn;

-(void)thing { 
    self.firstTurn = [[TheMove alloc] initWithMove:MoveTwo];
    self.firstTurn.move = MoveOne;
}
```

Objective-C inference is strictly enforced. If you don't say that its exposed to Objective-C, it's not exposed.

Also style point. Prefer capitalised class names `TheMove` not `theMove`.